# Tensorflow program stucks in reading tfrecord

Tags: tensorflow

I don't know whats going wrong with this small program.

Here is a snippet of the mcve-writer:

```py
def convert_to_example():
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
          'bboxes': _floats_feature([0.,1.])
          }))
    return example

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_file)
...
for filename in filenames:
    ...
    example = convert_to_example()
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
```

This is how I read the examples:

```py
filename = '/path/to/file'
record_iter = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=filename)
example = tf.train.Example()
l = []
for record in record_iter:
    example.ParseFromString(record)
    bboxes = example.features.feature['bboxes'].float_list.value[:]
    l.append(bboxes)

print(l)
```

I have narrowed down the problem in:

- it works with `bytes_list`
- it works with `int64_list` if the list is just one integer but not a list of integers
- it works with `float_list` if the list is just one float but not a list of floats

So, if I use a list of floats/integers, the execution reaches a deadlock or crushes. If I use a float/integer everything runs smooth.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is system dependent. On the workstation works just fine but not in my pc. I opened an issue in [github.com](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13039).